# SunPKCS11 provider in MacOS for Firefox

Tags: java, macos, firefox, pkcs#11

I managed to get the `SunPKCS11` to work with Firefox ESR 52.0 under Windows, but I am unable to get it to load in MacOS. I've already tried several different configuration and directly loading it via `PKCS11` but nothing worked, can anyone give me some pointer?

pkcs11.cfg configuration as follow:

```
name = FirefoxKeyStore
library = "/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/fixed-for-java-runtime/libsoftokn3.dylib"
attributes = compatibility
nssArgs = "configdir='/Users/helloworld/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/wasdwasd.default-1453211557245' certPrefix='' keyPrefix='' secmod='secmod.db' flags='readOnly' "
slot = 2
```

Then in Java, I've tried to load it like this:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("pkcs11.cfg");
Provider provider = new SunPKCS11(fis);
Security.addProvider(provider);
```

However this immediately gives me the following error:

```
sunpkcs11: Initializing PKCS#11 library /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/fixed-for-java-runtime/libsoftokn3.dylib
sunpkcs11: Multi-threaded initialization failed: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_DEVICE_ERROR
Exception in thread "main" java.security.ProviderException: Initialization failed
at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:376)
at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:107)
```

You maybe asking why do I load the `.dylib` from the weird folder, that's because I used `install_name_tool` in MacOS to change the `@executable_path` to `@loader_path` in order to get the library dependency to work (since I'm trying to run this in Eclipse rather than from Firefox itself).

I also tried to use the solution suggested here: [How to finalize SunPKCS11 Provider after it is initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37868757/how-to-finalize-sunpkcs11-provider-after-it-is-initialized) and it was a no-go either... I get the same error.

As well as trying various different configuration settings mentioned here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/PKCS11/Module_Specs#Softoken_Specific_Parameters

**EDIT1**

I tried the method mentioned by @FaithReaper but it still throw the same error. I tried changing the slot value to `0`, `1` or `-1` and result the same. It looks like there are problem loading the underlaying `PKCS11` object.

```
Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_DEVICE_ERROR
at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_Initialize(Native Method)
at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11$SynchronizedPKCS11.C_Initialize(PKCS11.java:1545)
at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.getInstance(PKCS11.java:157)
at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.<init>(SunPKCS11.java:330)
```

I dunno if this would help, but I ran the `modutil` on the FireFox profile and is dumping this info:

```
modutil -dbdir "/Users/eto/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/ew2g332o.default-1453211557245" -rawlist

library= name="NSS Internal PKCS #11 Module" 
parameters="configdir=/Users/eto/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/ew2g332o.default-1453211557245 certPrefix= keyPrefix= secmod=secmod.db flags=readOnly " 
NSS="Flags=internal,critical trustOrder=75 cipherOrder=100 slotParams=(1={slotFlags=[RSA,DSA,DH,RC2,RC4,DES,RANDOM,SHA1,MD5,MD2,SSL,TLS,AES,Camellia,SEED,SHA256,SHA512] askpw=any timeout=30})"
```

> Listing of PKCS #11 Modules
>
> 1. NSS Internal PKCS #11 Module
>       uri: pkcs11:library-manufacturer=Mozilla%20Foundation;library-description=NSS%20Internal%20Crypto%20Services;library-version=3.33
>      slots: 2 slots attached    status: loaded
>
>    slot: NSS Internal Cryptographic Services  token: NSS Generic Crypto
>      Services    uri:
>      pkcs11:token=NSS%20Generic%20Crypto%20Services;manufacturer=Mozilla%20Foundation;serial=0000000000000000;model=NSS%203
>
>    slot: NSS User Private Key and Certificate Services    token: NSS
>      Certificate DB      uri:
>      pkcs11:token=NSS%20Certificate%20DB;manufacturer=Mozilla%20Foundation;serial=0000000000000000;model=NSS%203

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The libraries provided by Firefox in Mac OS X might actually be completely broken or non-functional if execute outside of FireFox.

After trying many different combination of configuration and ways, I finally got it working **by NOT using the libraries from Firefox**...

Here is the step by step ways to get it to work:

1. Install homebrew in your Mac
2. Run `brew install nss`
3. Run `brew install nspr`
4. You may need to manually link them with `brew link nss` and `brew link nspr`
5. In the configuration file, you need to point it to your homebrew `libsoftokn3.dylib`, like so `library = /usr/local/opt/nss/lib/libsoftokn3.dylib`

Then your Java code should be able to load the Firefox keystore under Mac OS X... I've filed a bug [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1418065). The ticket contains a working [sample code](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1418065#c1) on how to instantiate the PKCS11, load the Firefox keystore and list the aliases from the store.

This was definitely a nightmare working with Firefox... but at least I got it working... Who would've thought the libraries they provided doesn't work (but it worked in Windows!)? :P

For completeness, I've included the sample code directly in this post as well:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Sample {

    private KeyStore load(String lib, String profile) throws Exception
    {
        String config = "library = " + lib + "\n" + 
                "name = FirefoxKeyStore\n" + 
                "attributes = compatibility\n" + 
                "nssArgs = \"configDir='" + profile + "' certPrefix='' keyPrefix='' secmod='secmod.db' flags='readOnly,forceOpen,optimizeSpace' \"\n" + 
                "slot = 2\n";

        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(config.getBytes());
        Provider provider = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(bais);
        Security.addProvider(provider);

        return KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Sample s = new Sample();

        String profile = "/Users/blah/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/yougottachangethis";
        String[] libs = { 
            //"/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/libsoftokn3.dylib",
            "/usr/local/opt/nss/lib/libsoftokn3.dylib"
        };

        for (String lib : libs) {
            System.out.println("TRYING >>> " + lib);
            try {
                KeyStore ks1 = s.load(lib, profile);

                ks1.load(null, null);
                for (String alias : Collections.list(ks1.aliases())) {
                    System.out.println(alias);  
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output of the `otool` from Mac (included for FaithReaper's comments):

```
otool -L libsoftokn3.dylib
libsoftokn3.dylib:
/usr/local/opt/nss/lib/libsoftokn3.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 253.0.0)
/usr/local/Cellar/nss/3.34/lib/libnssutil3.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/local/opt/nspr/lib/libplc4.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/local/opt/nspr/lib/libplds4.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/local/opt/nspr/lib/libnspr4.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1238.0.0)
```

Comment: I forgot to say but how do you config the system env variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? `nss` depends on  `nspr`, with no doubt.

Comment: I'm not sure whether Mac loads the library differently vs Linux, but my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is blank, and when I use `otool -L libsoftokn3.dylib` I could see that is already linked to `/usr/local/opt/nspr/lib/libnspr4.dylib`.

Comment: Hm..... I think `libsoftokn3.so` resides in the folder of nss, not nspr, and the name in Linux is as-is, not linked to `libnspr4.so`. So this may be the problem. Add this system variable pointing to the folder where you have `libsoftokn3.dylib` (not link, but the real file), and try again. Can you investigate where nss resides?

Comment: If you look at my example, `libsoftokn3.dylib` is already in nss folder. See `/usr/local/opt/nss/lib/libsoftokn3.dylib` which is how homebrew links it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I have noticed the different way you insert/add `Provider` with me. Can you try to add the `Provider` this way? (it may be irrelavent)

```
Provider p = new SunPKCS11(new ByteArrayInputStream(config.getBytes()));
Security.insertProviderAt(p, 1);
KeyStore.Builder builder = null;
builder = KeyStore.Builder.newInstance("PKCS11", p, 
    new KeyStore.CallbackHandlerProtection(new UtilTarjetas().new CustomCallbackHandler()));
cardKeyStore = builder.getKeyStore();
```

Then, maybe you can try the approach here:

https://github.com/avocado-framework/avocado/issues/1112

That is:

> apahim commented on 7 Apr 2016
>
> @will-Do, nss folks were able to track this issue down and seems like they are going to consider a change in `NSS_InitContext()`, which should include a `SECMOD_RestartModules(PR_FALSE)` after a `fork()`. Anyway, they also provided a better workaround than the one I provided you. If you set the environment variable `NSS_STRICT_NOFORK` to `DISABLED` then the code is expected to work. It worked for me and I'd like to check if it works for you as well. Looking forward to see your results.

Also, some sources suggests that it may be a token or slot problem. You can try to change slot index to `0`, or `-1`.

Comment: First of all, thank you for helping. But the problem seems to be at initializing `SunPKCS11` level, it throws the `CKR_DEVICE_ERROR` before I even `insertProviderAt` or `addProvider`. And the `CKR_DEVICE_ERROR` is being thrown by `sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_Initialize(Native Method)` See my updated in the post.