# How to reload keys of Java security KeyStore?

Tags: keystore, pkcs#11, hsm

```
Provider p = new SunPKCS11(configName);
char[]pin = "****".toCharArray();
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11", p);
ks.load(null, this.pin);

if (-1 == Security.addProvider(this.p)) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Could not add security provider");
}
```

How can I reload the keys ? Every time I run the code, I get the same instance of a KeyStore object, so the same keys.

Comment: So as per what you are saying, when you get the same instance of the the KeyStore object, are you not able to load/retrieve the newly generated keys?

Comment: Yes, I am not able to reload the keys. They are the same

Answer (score 0):

Here, I see that you are not loading any keystore eg no JSK file. Please see the below sample code

```
File f = new File(kStoreName);
if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()){
   try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f.getAbsolutePath())){
     ks.load(fis, storePassword.toCharArray());
  }
}
```

Comment: The question mentions PKCS11 KeyStore, which is a hardware token based. Your answer mentions `JKS`, which is a file based KeyStore (soft). It will not work for PKCS11 KeyStore.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the Sun Provider implementation caches the `Provider` instance. Hence you are getting the instance in your application. One way to overcome this is to manually finalize the PKCS11 provider. You can find it in my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37868757/how-to-finalize-sunpkcs11-provider-after-it-is-initialized).

Add a property to your provider instance `p`:

```
p.setProperty("pkcs11LibraryPath", library);
```

And then finalize the `PKCS` provider manually before fetching the keys:

```
PKCS11 pkcs11 = PKCS11.getInstance(((sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11) provider).getProperty("pkcs11LibraryPath"), null, null, true);
pkcs11.C_Finalize(PKCS11Constants.NULL_PTR);
```